# How to Serve Static Content for Sparkjava Running on Tomcat as Filter

Tags: tomcat, servlets, filter, static-files, spark-java

We have a web service built by Sparkjava micro framework. It has a UI which uses HTML, CSS, javascript. It was served by Sparkjava's embedded Jetty server and everything works fine.

Now we want to serve the Sparkjava app using Tomcat. As described in its official document, the Sparkjava app can be run as a Filter (SparkFilter) specified in web.xml.

Tomcat can serve the app but seems fail to render the page with static contents. The html templates are under `src/main/resources/templates` and they works fine. The `static` folder, which contains js, css, etc. folders is `src/main/resources/static`, but it seemed not be picked up. The access for static contents such as `/js/select2.min.js` returns 404 from the server. In the entry of Sparkjava app, we have `staticFiles.location("/static");` All these settings worked good for embedded jetty, but does not work for Sparkjava app running as a filter on Tomcat.

So I am wondering how the Sparkjava web app correctly pick up static files if running on Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution: we can delete the ROOT folder in the webapps folder, and put a ROOT.war inside the webapps folder. The ROOT.war is the app you want to be served. It has to be renamed as ROOT.war.